Cross-account CloudTrail logging
I am trying to configure Cross-account CloudTrail logging but i am facing issue when creating trail. Getting below error message.

We can not fetch current bucket access policy for bucket cloud***********, thus we did not try to update it. Please check the bucket policy manually if needed
InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException
Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket: cloud**********

in order to resolved this i went to destination account bucket and trying to check the bucket policy but it was empty. what type of permission i need to configure to allow cloudTrail from different account to do logging into another account?

The S3 bucket in the destination account needs a bucket policy that grants the CloudTrail service from the source account permission to write logs to the bucket.
Here's an example bucket policy:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<your-bucket-name>/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWSSourceAccount": "<source_account_id>"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

This policy allows the CloudTrail service from the source account (<source_account_id>) to put objects (logs) and set access control lists (ACLs) on objects within the specified S3 bucket ().
Applying the Policy
Verifying the Configuration
aws s3 get-bucket-policy --bucket <your-bucket-name>

This command should output the current bucket policy for your reference.
Ensure the IAM user or role you're using to create the CloudTrail trail has the necessary permissions to manage CloudTrail and S3 resources.
